# SQL Selection of products in a single category

Tags: sql, mysql, coldfusion

So here is what I am trying to do. My boss wants to put all vehicles that we have on our homepage and randomly pull 8 of them at a time. The way our database schema is setup has the products, and categories in separate tables using a cross reference to locate the category the product falls under. The table with the categories has a parent that is a direct ID from another category. So here is the SQL that I came up with.

```
  SELECT      product.productID, 
              product.productSKU, 
              product.price, 
              product.name,
             product.stateInd, 
              category.parentID,
              category.categoryID,
              prod_cat.productID FROM category

LEFT JOIN prod_cat
     ON prod_cat.categoryID = category.categoryID
LEFT JOIN product
     ON product.productID = prod_cat.productID

WHERE category.parentID =  <cfqueryparam value="#catID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" /> AND product.name <> "" AND RAND() 

LIMIT 8
```

I hope that all makes sense. I am just having the hardest time not only pulling 8 products but also making sure those 8 products are unique. Oh and I did try putting DISTINCT after the select but the product was still selected twice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DISTINCT should work.  If it doesn't, try to `group by productId`.  To select random rows, order by `rand()` instead of the `where rand()` construct.

Combining the two:

```
WHERE  category.parentID = <cfqueryparam value="#catID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"/>
       AND product.name <> ""
GROUP BY
       product.productID
ORDER BY
       RAND() 
LIMIT  8
```

Comment: Ok cool! I was working on it some more and got the order by rand thing figured out...but it was still duplicating. That's when I realized we have 2 products with the same name, same picture just different part numbers...if that makes sense :) Anyways I will try the order by things too! Thanks so much! +

Answer (score 0):

I'd pull the 8 unique products in a sub-query, then use that in the rest of your query.

In very rough pseudo-code:

```
select ...
    from (select 8 distinct random product IDs from product table) p
        left join prod_cat
           on p.productID = prod_cat.productID
        left join category
           on prod_cat.categoryID = category.categoryID
    ...
```

Comment: I was about to post same.. Select 8 products first, then do joins.

Comment: Ok! I like this take on it too. Would this improve performance any?

Comment: @Nathan: Test and compare both versions.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Joe beat me for this answer, but I was not sure how to put code in comment, so here is my answer.

I am not sure if categoryID will give single row or multiple rows for your input, if it is single row, you can very well use `=` instead of `in`

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM product
         WHERE product.productID in (
            SELECT productID 
              FROM prod_cat
             WHERE categoryID in (  
                   SELECT categoryID 
                     FROM category 
                    WHERE parentID = 
                          <cfqueryparam 
                           value="#catID#" 
                           cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" /> 
                             )
               AND name <> ''
             ORDER BY rand()
             LIMIT 8
              ) p
INNER JOIN prod_cat ON p.productID=prod_cat.productID
INNER JOIN category ON prod_cat.categoryID=category.categoryID
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks I man definitely going to have to see about testing both ways! Thanks for your help. UPDATE: Just tried it out...and unfortunately my version of MySQL doesn't support some of the features of the above sub queries. Definitely wish it would work wanted to give this a try :-/